# FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed when adding EJS to template

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to iterate through my JSON data in EJS from node / express, and when it's on the 6th pin throw a different pin into the flexbox.

When I try to add the code this way a fatal error (blow) pops up. How can I achieve what I am looking to do without fatal errors?

Thanks!

```
<% for(i=0; i < articles.length; i++) { %>

                <div class="pin" style="margin:1.25rem;">
                    <a href="/blog/<%- articles[i].slug %>">
                            <img class="blog-img" src="<%- articles[i].image %>" alt="blog post" style="width:20%;"/>
                    </a>
                    <h2><%- articles[i].title %></h2>
                    <p>
                        <%- articles[i].summary %>
                    </p>
                    <a class="readmore" style="position:relative; margin-top:2rem;" href="/blog/<%- articles[i].slug %>">READ MORE</a>
                </div>



                <% if( i = 5 ) { %>
                    <div class="pin" style="margin:1.25rem;">
                        <img src="images/logo-dark@2x.png" alt="Dome Logo" />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input onSubmit="submitData()" id="prospect-form" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" style="vertical-align: baseline; display:inline-block; background-color: white; border: none;" />
                            <button onSubmit="submitData()" id="form-submit" onClick="submitData()" class="btn btn-active" type="submit" style="display: inline-block">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <% } %>

    <% } %>
```

Error:
    <--- Last few GCs --->

```
[5347:0x103000000]    37746 ms: Mark-sweep 372.1 (379.5) -> 372.0 (377.5) MB, 1362.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort 
[5347:0x103000000]    53315 ms: Mark-sweep 906.8 (912.3) -> 548.7 (556.8) MB, 197.0 / 0.4 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 15568 ms) allocation failure GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x359bac9a66a1 <JS Object>
    2: /* anonymous */ [0x3ebc6f402311 <undefined>:~1] [pc=0x5a9ee9bbaad](this=0x1f1e6d598689 <JS Global Object>,locals=0x1606c8d792c9 <an Object with map 0x31a5701d9701>,escape=0x1606c8d62179 <JS Function exports.escapeXML (SharedFunctionInfo 0x1606c8d616b1)>,include=0x1606c8d79281 <JS Function include (SharedFunctionInfo 0x1606c8d737c9)>,rethrow=0x1606c8d79239 <JS Function rethrow (SharedFunc...

FATAL ERROR: invalid array length Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Heap::AllocateUninitializedFixedArray(int) [/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray(int) [/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastElementsAccessor<v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::FastPackedObjectElementsAccessor, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::ElementsKindTraits<(v8::internal::ElementsKind)2> >::AddArguments(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSArray>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FixedArrayBase>, v8::internal::Arguments*, unsigned int, v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::Where) [/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/node]
 7: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::DoArrayPush(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/Users//.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/node]
 8: 0x5a9ee48ed46
```

EDIT: That if statement is absolutely killing my machine. If I leave that if statement in there node uses 98% of my CPU and 1gb of RAM. If I take it out it returns to normal. Normal is about 60MB of ram and 0% of my CPU.

Comment: Can you post the iteration itself and an example of how your JSON is structured?

Comment: I added in the for loop

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/2694) can help.

Comment: I saw that. That if statement is absolutely killing my machine. If I leave that if statement in there it uses 98% of my CPU and 1gb of RAM. **If I take it out it returns to normal**

Comment: I think you should <% if(i == 5) %> and not <% if(i=5) %>

Comment: Thow this in an answer and I will accept it. Would love to know why = causes such a memory issue.

Comment: Still can't fully answer until we'll get to the real problem. What do you mean by 'not rendering'?

Comment: Edited. I lied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop gets stuck since you're trying to attach the value 5 to *i*  inside your if condition, instead of using the `==` comparison parameter to check its' value.

Your `if` statement should be

```
<% if( i == 5 ) { %>
```